# Using protocol methods as curried functions: attempting to store a function reference to a protocol blueprinted method crashes the compiler

Tags: swift, currying

#### Background

As per Swift Evolution Proposal [SE-0002](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md), curried function declarations has been removed from Swift as of Swift 3. We may, however, use instance methods as curried functions and partially apply these to instances of the defining type, e.g.:

```
struct Foo {
    func bar(_ num: Int) { print("bar \(num)!") }
}

let barFunc = Foo.bar
let fooInstance = Foo()
let partiallyApplied = barFunc(fooInstance)

// invoke remaining (Int) argument
partiallyApplied(42) // bar 42!
```

As compared to just invoking the instance method directly upon the instance:

```
fooInstance.bar(42)  // bar 42!
```

#### Query

Now, a protocol type cannot be instantiated in itself, but some concrete type conforming to it can be typed as the protocol type, and, given that default implementations exist, fully make use of instance methods declared and defined in the protocol and extensions to it, respectively (or, making use of custom implementations of it). E.g., with a method call `bar(42)` dynamically dispatched as below:

```
protocol Foo {
    func bar(_ num: Int)
}

extension Foo {
    func bar(_ num: Int) { print("bar \(num)!") }
}

struct ConcreteFoo : Foo { }

struct AnotherConcreteFoo : Foo { 
    func bar(_ num: Int) { print("barbar \(-num)!") }
}

var foo: Foo = ConcreteFoo()
foo.bar(42) // bar 42!
foo = AnotherConcreteFoo()
foo.bar(42) // barbar -42!
```

Based on the background section above, we could argue that we should likewise be able to use a protocol blueprinted method (say, `Foo.bar`) as a curried function much the same way as for the instance methods above, whereafter we, arguably, could partially apply it to any type conforming to the protocol:

```
let barFunc = Foo.bar
```

Attempting to store such a protocol method reference crashes the compiler, however.

- **[Q1]:** Since this seemingly crashes the compiler, this should be a bug, right? If so, has anyone already seen a bug report for it (I can't find one)?
- **[Q2]:** Would it be reasonable to be able to use a protocol blueprinted method in the same currying approach as for an instance method (with the purpose of partially applying it to instances of types conforming to it), or would this break some fundamental "rule" of Swift that I'm missing (method dispatch for protocol typed types)?

*(Tested with Swift 3.1.1 / Linux (x86-64))*

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44589459/2976878 :)

Comment: @Hamish ow, nice, thanks! Too bad I didn't find that thread on my own directly and ended up writing to overly long question instead :) will dupe mark.

Comment: Also worth noting that [SE-0042](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0042-flatten-method-types.md) will be coming along at some point, changing the curried instance methods to just flat functions (i.e from `(Foo) -> (Int) -> Void` to `(Foo, Int) -> Void`).

Comment: @Hamish I didn't know about that one, that's nice to avoid type mismatch also, between curried functions and other matching (but currently mis-type-matched) flat functions.